# How to split the average of a column into multiple columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Consider this table, called `fruit_sales`. Each row is an instance of a fruit being purchased, the columns being:

- The day on which the purchase occurred
- The type of fruit
- Its price

For example:

```
| Day | Item   | Price |
|=====|========|=======|
| 01  | Apple  | 1.5   |
| 03  | Apple  | 1     |
| 01  | Apple  | 3     |
| 02  | Banana | 2     |
| 01  | Apple  | 1.5   |
| 02  | Apple  | 2     |
| 01  | Banana | 1     |
| 01  | Banana | 1.5   |
```

I would like to derive a table wherein each row is a day, the columns being:

- The day
- The average price of Apples for that day
- The average price of Bananas for that day

For example:

```
| Day | Avg Apple $ | Avg Banana $ |
|=====|=============|==============|
| 01  | 2           | 1.25         |
| 02  | 2           | 2            |
| 03  | 1           | 0            |
```

I can create a query to calculate the average price of *all* fruit per hour grouped by day:

```
SELECT Day, AVG(price) FROM `fruit_sales` GROUP BY Day;
```

...but I can't figure out how to split the average into one column for each fruit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
  #standardSQL
  SELECT Day, 
    IFNULL(AVG(IF(Item = 'Apple', Price, NULL)), 0) AS `Avg_Apple`,
    IFNULL(AVG(IF(Item = 'Banana', Price, NULL)), 0) AS `Avg_Banana`
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY Day
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
  #standardSQL
  WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
    SELECT '01' Day, 'Apple' Item,  1.5 Price UNION ALL
    SELECT '03', 'Apple',  1 UNION ALL
    SELECT '01', 'Apple',  3 UNION ALL
    SELECT '02', 'Banana', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT '01', 'Apple',  1.5 UNION ALL
    SELECT '02', 'Apple',  2 UNION ALL
    SELECT '01', 'Banana', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT '01', 'Banana', 1.5 
  )
  SELECT Day, 
    IFNULL(AVG(IF(Item = 'Apple', Price, NULL)), 0) AS `Avg_Apple`,
    IFNULL(AVG(IF(Item = 'Banana', Price, NULL)), 0) AS `Avg_Banana`
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY Day
  -- ORDER BY Day
```

with result

```
Row Day Avg_Apple   Avg_Banana   
1   01      2.0     1.25     
2   02      2.0     2.0  
3   03      1.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need group by item as well addition to day

like
`SELECT Day, ITEM,AVG(price) FROM fruit_sales GROUP BY Day, ITEM ;` this will show you each item wise each days avg

Comment: The current will show o/p in form of rows and if in case you still require the same in columns as well you need to use `pivot` not sure if its directly in big query or not but certainly theres something similar as `Nth Nest(..) etc ` in big query

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really specify which database you are using. Mikhail's answer is great for standard SQL, but if you are using SQL Server 2005+, then you can use the PIVOT function to transform the data from rows into columns.  It's easy if you know the list of fruits up front, but in order to get dynamic columns you need to generate dynamic SQL from the list of fruits.

```
declare @cols as nvarchar(max),
@query  as nvarchar(max)

select @cols = stuff((select ',' + quotename(Item) 
                from fruit_sales
                group by Item
                order by Item
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select [Day],' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select [Day], Item, Price
            from fruit_sales
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            Avg(Price)
            for Item in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query);
```

Comment: Note that the question was tagged with "bigquery"

Comment: Oops!  Sorry, totally missed that tag.  Well, the pivot was still fun to write!